# _itemFailedToPlayToEnd when playing local mp4 using UIWebView

Tags: ios, iphone, html, video, uiwebview

I am trying to play a local mp4 video using html5 video as follows.

```
<video id="media" controls="true" preload="auto" src="xxxx.mp4">
    </video>
```

but its does not play. I get following error

```
_itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
   kind = 1;
   new = 2;
   old = 0;
  }
```

Any suggestion for playing video in UIWebView will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, so that you aren't hosting the video on your website is post the video to youtube, and embed it into your website so that way all you do is copy and paste the embedded code into your html...or you can do this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

NSString *embedHTML = @"\
<html><head>\
<style type=\"text/css\">\
body {\
background-color: transparent;\
color: white;\
}\
</style>\
</head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
<embed id=\"yt\"     src=\"http://www.businessfactors.de/bfcms/images/stories/videos/defaultscreenvideos.mp4\"     type=\"application/x-shockwave-mp4\" \
width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
</body></html>";

webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 412.0)];

[webView setOpaque:NO];
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, webView.frame.size.width,     webView.frame.size.height];
[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
}
```

Try This, Should do the trick